# How to override authentication for certain web pages....?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication

Well I am having following code written in master page: -

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Loginpage.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

Now it will redirect to "Loginpage.aspx" if authentication fails.

Now what If I would like to override this authentication for few pages. Also note that the number of pages and page names are not available at design time, so cannot include the aspx page names in configuration file.

Is there anyway to override authentication for few aspx pages?

-Anil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Henrik's answer is a good one and should work if properly implemented. However, this is another option which tackles the problem more from a configuration standpoint. I know that you mentioned that you won't know the page names ahead of time so you can't include an entry in web.config for each page BUT web.config allows you to secure folders too. You could have all pages that require authentication placed in a folder called "AuthRequired" and all pages that don't require authentication placed in a folder called "Anonymous", for example. Then in your web config you could have the following entries:

```
<location path="AuthRequired">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
<location path="Anonymous">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: thanks will try it.... but still would you please clarify why you had written both <deny users="?"> and <allow users="*"> in "AuhtRequired" location path?

Comment: The rules are evaluated in order, top down. <deny users="?" /> denies all anonymous users. <allow users="*" /> allows all users. In the case of the AuthRequired path, you don't want any anonymous users so they will hit that deny first and not be allowed to view the page without logging in. Any authenticated users will not meet the criteria of that first deny rule and will hit the second rule which allows all users. Hopefully I explained that well.

Comment: and what if I had not added <allow user="*"/> in it...is it will not allow any user to visit the page even after authentication?

Comment: I believe it would then default to whatever you had set globally in web.config which typically when you enable forms authentication you have something like this in the main system.web section: <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the AuthorizeRequest event and act accordingly. Create your own Http Module to do this.

Three options:

- use the configuration settings above together with generating folders with web.config entries. This is a pretty shoddy way of doing it.
- listen to the event AuthenticateRequest, the code looks something like this:

  ```
  public class UserAuthenticationModule : IHttpModule
  {
  private HttpApplication _Context;
  private RoleManagerModule _RoleManager;

  public void Init(HttpApplication context)
  {
      _Context = context;
      context.AuthenticateRequest += AuthenticateUser;
      _RoleManager = (RoleManagerModule)context.Modules["RoleManager"];
      _RoleManager.GetRoles += roleManager_GetRoles;
  }

  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727960/how-to-keep-roleprovider-from-overriding-custom-roles
  private void roleManager_GetRoles(object sender, RoleManagerEventArgs e)
  {
      if (_Context.User is UserPrincipal)
          e.RolesPopulated = true; // allows roles set in AuthenticateUser to stick.
  }

  private static void AuthenticateUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      var app = (HttpApplication) sender;
      if (app.Context == null) return;

      var user = app.Context.User;

      // not signed in, forms authentication module takes care of redirecting etc.
      if (user == null) return;
      // we're done then.
      if (user is IUser) return;

      var userEntity = IoC.Resolve<IUserRepository>().FindByUserName(user.Identity.Name);

      // we can't find the user in the database.
      if (userEntity == null)
          throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("User \"{0}\" deleted from, or renamed in, database while logged into application.", 
              user.Identity.Name));

      // signed in, assigning user, which should assign Thread.CurrentPrincipal as well (it wouldn't do this on PostAuthenticateRequest).
      app.Context.User = new UserPrincipal(userEntity);
      userEntity.SetAuthenticated();
  }

  //Implement IDisposable.
  public void Dispose()
  {
  }
  }
  ```

If your UserPrincipal implements IPrincipal, then IsInRole is used to give role-based access to your pages.

- The service-oriented way; set up a small transparent proxy server. List your endpoints/uri-s in a dynamic store, like what you are describing. Set up an authorization service such as Rhino Security; expose its service interfaces as a REST-API or a request/reply interface or something. Assume from the web app's perspective that every request is allowed and take care of where you redirect. In the proxy server, e.g. nginx which is a very nice asynchronous C-based proxy server on Linux, call your authorization service from a filter/module. 'Security in depth' and you can share configuration for security in the Authorization Service.

---

The principle that you follow is that if something is not allowed in a web application you do `throw new HttpException(405, "The current operation you are trying to perform is now allowed for your role or user or chosen path in life")` in the AuthorizeRequest event. **Note that there's a AuthenticateRequest and another AuthorizeRequest event**

Comment: Well I am having pages which are to be created on a fly....some of them should abide with authentication process...(if user visit those pages it should redirect it first to login page if authentication fails or if not at all authenticated)....but some of them should not go through authentication process....so here is the problem what if the pages which are created on fly need to bypass authentication process (I mean even though user has visited this page without logging into the system, user should be allowed to visit that page).... how can you  achieve this....

Comment: ok, posted a longish answer while waiting for my oven to heat so I can cook and eat my pizza.

Comment: @Henrik, would you please let me know how to make use of  "AuthorizeRequest" (which you mentioned in second option) while adding dynamic pages. also how is it solves the purpose of bypassing authentication process (few pages which will be created on a fly)...as from your code it seems that it is not bypassing any page....so still it is not cleared to me....how you can make pages to bypass authentication using AuthorizeRequest option?

Comment: You haven't stated what Authentication framework you are using so I can't answer how to avoid it. But if you are using FormsAuthentication you can either just allow a specific sub-path and manually authenticate that sub-path WHEN you want authentication, using the above code; OR you can remove the forms authentication module and write your own authentication code.

Comment: Because the default is to allow the request, to the lack of a deny means allow.

Comment: @Henrik, we are using FormAuthentication. but for some dynamic page we need to bypass Authentication process(we don't want to authenticate users at all to view those pages) for e.g. FAQ / Terms and Conditions / Mode of Payment - (these are just examples there are many dynamic pages where we don't want to authenticate users at all). So would you please let me know that instead of using "<location path> " in config, can I use AuthenticateRequest (specified by you) to bypass authentication for certain dynamic pages?

Comment: If you want consulting you can PM me and we can work out a deal. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should usually have **one** point where users can be **authenticated** - get confirmed that they are who they claim they are. Next, you are probably talking about **authorisation**, which is a matter of allowing/denying performing certain operation to the user, like sending a GET request. Authorisation rules in a simple scenarios can be configured in the web.config through *location* element, as presented by Tom.

Comment: As we are using FormAuthentication for authenticating user with LDAP. But for some reason for few pages, we don't want redirect it to Login page. so what are the methods as we don't know the name of the pages while coding.

Comment: @anil I am not sure if this will work, but worth trying. You can try putting authentication tag in the location. Say, if you have page called *SpecialPage.aspx* and you want special authentication for it, create a *location* tag pointing to the page and define dedicated authentication for it. E.g.                           _<location path="SpecialPage.aspx">
 <system.web>
 <authentication mode="Forms" >
   <forms loginUrl="SpecialLogin.aspx" ... ></forms>
 </authentication>
 ...
 </system.web>
</location>_

Comment: I don't know whether my question is clear to you or not. As I had mention this many times that I don't know the names of pages in advance, Because the pages are getting generated on a fly. So I can't use the method you had specified.